# How to read XML parent node tag value in android

Tags: android, android-xml

I have a java code to read XML nodes, I want to add in the addition and want to read the parent node value also.

my XML file  sample is below:

```
 <breakfast_menu><food id=1><name> Belgian Waffles </name><price> $5.95 </price><description> two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup </description><calories> 650 </calories></food><food id=2><name>Strawberry Belgian waffles</name><price>$7.95</price><description>light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description><calories>900</calories></food></breakfast_menu>
```

and my code for parsing xml is :

```
public static String getProductItem(String pid, String item) {

    try {
        url = new URL("");
        urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    try {
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    }
    try {
        doc = dBuilder.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    } catch (SAXException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("food");

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;



                data = getTagValue(item, eElement);



        }
    }

    doc = null;
    dBuilder = null;

    return data;

}


private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
    NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0)
    .getChildNodes();
    Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

    return nValue.getNodeValue();
}
```

What I want to do is to read the "id" value of food, so if if I am searching for a food, it only checks those food nodes, whose id matched the food node id.

if I read by tag id, it reads all tags not specifically one tag. How to achieve it?

Comment: Note: I dono how to use Xpath in android; so suggest some other options pls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I missed somthing, is it just `String id = eElement.getAttribute("id");` that you're looking for?

You may want to look into using XPath to fetch out of your DOM.  getElementsByTagName has an irritating habit of ignoring the document structure.  (Also ought to be using a namespace and getElementsByTagNameNS :) )

Comment: I cannot use Xpath in android, I want to stick with DOM. is there any way to get the attribute in DOM?

Answer (score 4):

You can use XPath to easily find a set of nodes according to some criteria.
For example:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList nl = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//food[@id=22]", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

This code finds all food nodes with a given id in the document. [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) is a rich language for this kind of search criteria.

Comment: I can not use Xpath in Adnroid, is there any way I can do this in the above mentioned code.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but why can't you use it? I used XPath before on Android with no issues.

Answer (score 3):

[XPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html) is available for use in Android since API level 8. If it's an option for you, suppose your xml is placed in your project at

> /res/raw/food_list.xml

Given that, you may search for all  elements using this xpath syntax:

```
//food/@id
```

The above search expression will return a list of all `id` attributes that pertain to `<food>` elements wherever they are since root.

So if what you want is to fetch all those `id` attributes, you can do it as follows

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.food_list);
DocumentBuilderFactory fac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

try {
    Document doc = fac.newDocumentBuilder().parse(is);
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr;
    try {
         expr = xpath.compile("//food/@id");
         NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
         for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
              Node node = nl.item(i);
               // Considering the example XML at the end of this loop you will 
               // get the ids printed
              System.out.println(node.getNodeValue());
         }
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    is.close();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

A quick reference on XPath syntax and a bit of explanation can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp).

Comment: Good to know, Manoj I'm glad I could help :)